# "Unhandled Execution Error" when connecting to oracle from IIS hosted web application

Tags: oracle, iis, asp.net-2.0

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 web application that connects to a remote oracle database, the application visual studio but not on iis. I've tried windows 7, windows server 2008 R2 and windows server 2012.

It fails when hosted on IIS, with the following error message:

```
Unhandled Execution Error 

   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at AspDbTest._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\kourosh\c#\BasicRumTest20\AspDbTest\Default.aspx.cs:line 19
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)


Stack Trace: 

[OracleException (0x80004005)]
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable) +1514
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src) +51
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open() +5243
   AspDbTest._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\kourosh\c#\OracleTest_with_trace\AspDbTest\Default.aspx.cs:19
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

I also have a client C# app that works there.

I already enabled the 32 bit application option on iis.
Any ideas?

Comment: Classic ASP is a totally different thing, what you have is known as ASP.NET - better know the basics. Anyway first thing I would try is upgrading to latest .NET version or at least 4.0 which should be much more stable. My guess is that Oracle assembly is newer version, thus failing to work with the old versions you have in your application.

Comment: Also, please include your connection string.

Comment: I've already tried recompiling the code with 4.0 and deploying it with 4.0 pool...the same problem happened.

Comment: as for my connection string which bytheway is perfect and already works in other apps: connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = this-is-my-host-name)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = ORCL) ));User Id=my_user;Password=something_to_hide;" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"

Comment: Sorry, can't see what might be the problem. Too bad Oracle won't throw a better error. Did you try posting in Oracle support forums?

Comment: When running it locally, are you using Casini or IIS Express?

Comment: I do not think Oracle would be the one responsible. It's Microsoft (iis). On the same machine, I installed Microsoft WebMatrix and on that it works. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: I used IIS 7.5 which did not work. But as I said, it worked in visual studio and in WebMatrix.

Comment: I also tried using windows authentication and running it as the same user as in visual studio. Also tried added full control permissions on the C:\app folder which has the oracle driver. Neither of these work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the admin user for the pool (also enabled 32 bit), it did not seem to help. Finally, by chance, I rebooted the machine and it worked. With visual studio it immediately works, but iis apparently needs a reboot in order to work (but iisreset also does not help).